# Transformer with only three wires from an APC UPS

Tags: transformer, inductor

I was taking apart an older APC UPS and found a big transformer in it. The label says CLASS 130(B) NER-B82 430-0144 from Shenzhen Jingquanhua Electronics. DB-E186-3107A E208707. When I looked it up everything I could find described a transformer with some secondary tab. This doesn't have one. It has a black, red and white wire of 14AWG. I think this might be a choke but I don't know.
Does anyone have an idea, so I can look it up?

Thanks

Comment: These parts are usually custom made for the product, so the part number is simply a reference. So don't expect to find data on it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A transformer with only three connections could be an autotransformer, this has only one tapped winding and is cheaper to make then a dual winding transformer. It does not provide isolation of the downstream circuitry from the mains but there are however places in a UPS where this is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I looked it up and I see how it works now. Just getting back into electronics and have so much to learn again.

Answer (score 0):

A destructive way to know data about a transformer is unroll the transformer and count turns.. etc.
This is not always possible (es. potted transformers) but I made this by myself many times, obviously if you have your transformer data and cannot find an equivalent component you have to rebuild the transformer by yourself.